# JSP para desenvolvedores .NET

Tags: java, .net, asp.net, jsp

Sou desenvolvedor .NET que precisa entender um bug que ocorre numa aplicação JSP. (Não preciso compilar ou corrigir, só entender como o mesmo está usando o banco de dados e etc.)

Já tenho o Eclipse, solução carregada, tenho os fontes e etc. Mas preciso de um quick start na arquitetura. Ainda estou com dificuldades básicas do tipo essa página está sendo populada como?

Existe algum tipo de tutorial rápido para desenvolvedores de JSP para desenvolvedores .NET?

Tenho perguntas do tipo :

1. JSP está mais para ASP, ASP.NET ou ASP.NET MVC?
2. Tipo quais as diferenças entre ASP.NET e JSP, em que são similares e
   etc.
3. Existe codebehind?
4. Use-se controllers tipo no ASP.NET MVC?
5. Uma URL http://meusite/teste.do, onde encontro o arquivo jsp?

Comment: A princípio, não existe. Uma resposta explicando isso caberia melhor.

Answer (score 6):

> JSP está mais para ASP, ASP.NET ou ASP.NET MVC?

A princípio, para as três, embora não seja exatamente correto estabelecer este tipo de paralelo. [JSP é uma tecnologia de processamento de HTML](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_overview.htm), assim como a notação ASP, ASPX ou Razor. As três tecnologias da Microsoft usam, respectivamente, ASP Clássico e linguagens dentro do .NET para processar o conteúdo de marcação. JSP faz o mesmo com Java.

> Tipo quais as diferenças entre ASP.NET e JSP, em que são similares e etc.

Há mais similaridades que diferenças. Ambas processam uma página com marcações de forma a obter um resultado dinâmico, normalmente em HTML.

[Há algumas respostas sobre isso aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371300/technical-differences-between-asp-net-and-java-servlets-jsp).

> Existe codebehind?

JSP não é orientado a eventos. Aqui tem-se uma confusão com o ASP.NET Web Forms, que é uma *stack* de *frameworks*. JSP é apenas um *framework*, especializado na substituição de um documento anotado com a notação característica por conteúdo processado pelo Java.

> Use-se controllers tipo no ASP.NET MVC?

Assim como na resposta anterior, o ASP.NET MVC é uma arquitetura, uma *stack* de *frameworks*. Uma comparação mais equivalente seria JSP vs. Razor, ou JSP vs. ASPX.

Contudo, o Java possui seus próprios *frameworks* MVC que podem ser usados juntamente com o JSP, como o [Spring MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm) e o [Play! Framework](https://www.playframework.com/).

> Uma URL http://meusite/teste.do, onde encontro o arquivo jsp?

Depende do *framework*. Se for um *framework* MVC, por exemplo, normalmente estes arquivos ficam em um diretório `Views`.

Comment: É comum quando nos envolvemos com outras tecnologias, ter o hábito, que pode ser ruim, de fazer relações com o que já conhecemos. Por isso nesse sentido sua resposta é de grande ajuda para que eu não faça as relações erradas. Obrigado. Já ajuda no entendimento do que tenho pela frente.